# Youtube API OAuth'd Objects Losing Authentication When Distributed With Celery

Tags: python, api, oauth, youtube, celery

I'm using celery with the YouTube API to make asynchronous calls. I've created a class that contains the [authorized http connection (see: "complete example")](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts) to the Youtube Service. I pass an instance of that class to all of my celery tasks, but when I call the API, the response is 403, and I end up needing to re-authenticate for each task. When I run it synchronously without celery, there is no issue.

Clearly the http object is being tampered with. Could this be an issue w/ pickle (what I'm currently using for serialization), or is this a celery problem?

Thanks!

edit (for more information):

task:

```
@current_app.task(name='test.test_connection')
def testConnection(apiObj):
    http = apiObj.http
    print http
    print http.connections
    print http.other_connections
```

dispatcher:

```
def test():
    import httplib2
    o = ApiObj() #this connects to youtube and authorizes the http object
    h = o.http
    h.other_connections = {'test':httplib2.HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout('localhost',80,timeout=120)}
    print h
    print h.connections
    print h.other_connections
    tasks.testConection.s(o).delay()
```

In my custom api class, I have an Http object (from httplib2). From my task publisher, I print the connections in the http object, and then pass that object to the celery task, where I attempt to print them again.

results from dispatcher:

```
<httplib2.Http object at 0x293e6d0>
{'https:www.googleapis.com': <httplib2.HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout instance at 0x2a12b90>, 'https:accounts.google.com': <httplib2.HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout instance at 0x2a0be60>}
{'test': <httplib2.HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout instance at 0x29bc440>}
```

results from celery worker:

```
<httplib2.Http object at 0x43b4a50>
{}
{'test': <httplib2.HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout instance at 0x3c6df80>}
```

Even if I change the celery task to take the http object as a parameter, and I pass the variable `h` from the function `test` into the celery task, the results are the same.

I'm starting to think this is due to the pickling of the google oauth'd object.

Answer (score 0):

I tried passing just the http.connections dictionary, and I get this:

`kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Cannot pickle <type 'ssl.SSLContext'> objects`
`kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: <httplib2.HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout instance at 0x2e2c488> is not JSON serializable`
`kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: cannot represent an object: <httplib2.HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout instance at 0x3611680>`

The problem lies in pickling the SSL object, which is innately unpickle-able.